# Don't know how to resolve typedef correctly

Tags: c++, typedef

I think there seems to be a circular dependency of typedefs in my following code... Is there any way to get around this? This is a simplified expression of my problem. No matter where I put the typedef statement, it doesn't want to resolve correctly.

```
struct Item {
    int id;
    ItemList* ptrToList;
}

typedef std::list<Item> ItemList;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can resolve it like this (compiles under MSVC2012)

```
struct Item;
typedef std::list<Item> ItemList;

struct Item
{
    Item* item;
    ItemList list;
};
```

Note: my struct is slightly different than yours, but it still illustrates the point.

Comment: The *small difference* with the original might have implications beyond what you expect. I am not sure if you have not created undefined behavior with the little change there... The relevant quotes being in 9.2/2 and 17.6.4.8/2

Answer (score 1):

You can declare just a type name:

```
struct Item;
```

Then assemble the rest with that.

Answer (score 0):

Use forward declaration:

```
struct Item;
typedef std::list<struct Item> ItemList;
struct Item {
    int id;
    ItemList* ptrToList;
};
```